# Why is this code working? (NodeJS/Express asynchronous callbacks)

Tags: node.js, express

Is this code respecting the NodeJS async way of doing things?  It's fully working, but I don't understand why the `res.render` is inside the `Database.findOne` callback and not inside the `Database.aggregate` callback, even if I'm using the results of both `Database.findOne` and `Database.aggregate`.

However, if I put the `res.render` outside both the `Database.aggregate` and the `Database.findOne`, but still inside the `router.get` callback, then the code won't work at all **(edit: of course, in that case, I declare the variables outside the database queries)**. How come?  What is the correct NodeJS way of doing things?

Thanks

```
var _         = require('lodash');
var express   = require('express');
var Database = require('../models/database');
var router    = express.Router();
router.get('/:XXXX', function(req, res, next) {
var XXXX = req.params.XXXX;

var aggregationResults;
Database.aggregate([
    // pipeline
], function(err, results) {
    aggregationResults = results;
    if (err) return next(err);
});

Database.findOne({XXXX: XXXX}, function(err, XXXXresult){
    if(err) return next(err);

    res.render('page', {XXXXresult: XXXXresult, aggregationObject : aggregationResults[0]});


});
```

});

Comment: Try to read about scope
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md

Comment: @AhmadRezk   Yes, of course the variables are declared in the right scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you moved the `res.render` outside of the `findOne` callback, it will execute before the callbacks - you won't have any data. Those database operations are going to complete *after* the router `(req, res, next)` callback returns, after all.

In your current code, given that the `aggregate` and `findOne` functions are async, you have a race condition. If the `findOne` callback executes before the `aggregate` callback, you will get a `TypeError` as `aggregationResults` will be undefined.

The simplest way to fix this is to place `findOne` call inside the `aggregate` callback. But this is not actually a good idea because then the two functions will execute one after the other, which is slower than executing them simultaneously.

What you should really be doing is using Promises, and use something like `Promise.all` with 2 promises to send the response after both operations complete.

Comment: So, how do I fix the "race condition"?  (Sorry to ask :/ )

Comment: Sorry again, why is it not a good idea to put the `findOne` inside the `aggregate` callback? Thanks

Comment: It is not actually a good idea because then the two async functions will execute one after the other, which takes longer than executing them simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are calling two async database functions and passing a callback to each function. Here you first called `Database.aggregate()` and passing a callback which stores the result in a variable i.e. `aggregationResults`. Then you are calling `Database.findOne()` and passing a callback to it which sends the result of both the call.

Here it is working because your first database call (`Database.aggregate()`) is resolving before the second one (i.e.`Database.findOne()`). So in your second database's callback you are assuming that first database call's result is available.

But that may not be the case always. For example there are chances that first database might fail and second one passes. In that case there is no result of first database.

**What is the correct NodeJS way of doing things?**

Well earlier it used to be a nested callback but today you should use promise. Your code then will look something like this:

```
Database.aggregate([pipeline]).then(function(results) {
    aggregationResults = results;
    return Database.findOne({XXXX: XXXX});
}).then(function(XXXXresult){
    res.render('page', {XXXXresult: XXXXresult, aggregationObject : aggregationResults[0]});
});
```

You can use library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) to promisify your database methods.

Comment: This code is working without bluebird or only with bluebird? Thanks!

Comment: If your database methods are already returning promises then it will work. Otherwise you need to modify your database methods such that they return promise. You can either use bluebird alike libraries or can use native promises of nodejs to promisify them.

Comment: I recommend you to read a bit about promises first before jumping directly into this.

Comment: Because it is nested. The codes written with promises are more readable.

Comment: Great thanks!  I thought it was because of some technical reason that I wasn't able to see.